# Parsing month/day/year date format in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to parse the following date format in D3 for [line chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) visual:

```
10/29/2015
```

I have tried:

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%M-%d-%Y");
```

but it isn't working. Is it possible to parse this format in D3?

Answer (score 1):

Your date uses slashes whereas the specifier of your time format has hyphens in it. Defining it as

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%M/%d/%Y");
```

should do the trick.

```js
console.log(d3.time.format("%M-%d-%Y").parse("10/29/2015"));  // doesn't work
console.log(d3.time.format("%M/%d/%Y").parse("10/29/2015"));  // works
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had actually tried the slashes as well but to no avail. What ended up working was d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"). Not sure why but it parses it correctly.

Comment: As you can check by running the snippet, the slashes will correctly parse the dates. The format you provided will definitely not parse the date string provided in your question unless there is more to it we are not seeing. Could you set up an executable example demonstrating this?